# How to design an ontology concepts on a list of metadata correlated with other characteristics

Tags: artificial-intelligence, owl, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I'm quite new for ontology design and implementation. I am trying to implement an e-learning recommender system based on an ontology. basically the system should show learning resources to students based on their profile by matching the metadata attached to the profile to the metadata attached to learning resources (videos, pdfs, ppts...etc.).

Currently, I'm in the phase of designing the ontology. However, I'm finding difficulty trying to design the ontology as I have a list of correlation between metadata annotations. the system should match between metadata annotated on the student profile with another annotation on the resources. the table below an example of the correlations between the student and the learning resource metadata.
[Picture 1 (table of the relationships)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFyjz.png) another part of the table is in [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvUES.png).

the value ***active*** of the data element ***interactivity type*** is correlated with the learner characteristic ***active*** of the **Felder-Silverman** learning style model. Furthermore, when the value of the data element ***interactivity level*** is ***high***, the coincidence degree with the learners’ characteristic ***active*** is ***high*** (100% in column 3). In fact, there are 5 ranged (putted in order) values included in the data element ***interactivity level: very low, low, medium, high, and very high***, which could be associated respectively with the 5 ranged degrees (which associate the values of the data element interactivity level with the learners’ characteristics ***active*** of the ***Felder-Silverman*** learning style model) ***20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, and 100%.*** The degree increases when the value of the data element ***interactivity level*** increases.

the ***data element*** column represent the learning resources metadata and the learner ***characteristics represent*** the learner metadata. in the learner metadata, there are many attributes need to be taken into consideration. For example, Learning style; it is divided into two types of learning styles (Filder-Silverman and Honey-Mumford), Filder-Silverman has three categories of styles (Active/Reflective, Visual/Verbal and Sequential/Global), Each student have a percentage of all three categories but one value of each category such as a student can be Active 60%, Global 20% and Visual 80%. Note that a student **can't** be Active and Reflective/Sequential and Global/Visual and Verbal at the same time.

So students who have an ***active*** learning style with a high degree such as **80%** can see learning materials with ***interactivity type***: with a value of ***active*** and ***Interactivity level*** : with a value of ***high***

is it possible to design such a use case in ontology? and how would that be?? Please help!